# Does iterating the consistency of ZFC answer any natural questions?

Tags: logic, set-theory

The following is a natural question that occurred to me, but I'm not sure if it's even well-defined since I haven't read the literature on iterating consistency statements. Let $Con_0(ZFC)=Con(ZFC)$ and, inductively, let $Con_\alpha(ZFC)=Con(ZFC+\{Con_\beta(ZFC): \beta < \alpha\})$. First of all, does this give a well-defined formula in the language of set theory for every ordinal $\alpha$? If not, at what point and for what reason does it go wrong? If it does, since we know that the formal language of set theory only has countably many formulas, we know that this sequence of consistency statements must stop giving new formulas after a certain point. Is it known at what point it starts repeating itself? Also, why isn't the fact that it does repeat itself forever contrary to Godel's Second Incompleteness theorem?

Finally, let us call those statements that we are "committed to" all of those statements that are logical consequences of $ZFC+\{Con_\alpha(ZFC) : \alpha \in ON\}$ (or if this formulation is not well-defined for some reason, up to the highest alpha we can get to). Are there any natural set-theoretic (or non set-theoretic) statements that we are committed to but nonetheless are independent of ZFC? In particular, has anyone shown that we are not committed either way on CH?

Comment: Very interesting question!

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/164491/on-the-consistency-of-zfc-and-zf.

Answer (score 7):

This is a famous topic studied by Alan Turing in his dissertation *Systems of Logic Based on Ordinals* in 1939, and again by Soloman Feferman in 1962.

- "[Systems of Logic Based on Ordinals](http://www.turingarchive.org/browse.php/B/15)", Alan Turing, *Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society*, s2-45(1), 1939, pp. 161-228.
- "Transfinite Recursive Progressions of Axiomatic Theories", Solomon Feferman, *The Journal of Symbolic Logic* 27 (3), 1962, pp. 259-316. Restricted-access URL: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2964649

(Please feel free to edit this post to insert a link to a legitimate, freely available online version of Feferman's paper, if one exists.)

As for where things go wrong, one key issue is that creating a *formula* for $\text{Con}_\alpha(T)$ requires $\alpha$ to not only be an ordinal, but to be definable by a formula in some way. So the construction goes awry at the first $\alpha$ which is not definable in this way, which will be a *countable* ordinal due to some results of hyperarithmetical theory.

For a more modern treatment, you could look at Torkel Franzén, *Inexhaustibility: A Non-Exhaustive Treatment*, Lecture Notes in Logic v. 16, 2004.  (Link: [Review by John Baldwin](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~asl/bsl/1402/1402-004.ps))

Comment: Thanks for the references and answer! Do we know the least such ordinal where things go wrong? And do you have any info about the second part of the question - i.e. an example of a natural statement that is independent of ZFC but decided by adjoining however many iterations of consistency are well defined?

Comment: The least ordinal will depend on the theory at hand, but it will be related to the Church-Kleene ordinal $\omega_1^{CK}$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Kleene_ordinal . This is a countable ordinal, but large in the sense of this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_countable_ordinal . There will not be any nice closed expression for your ordinal. I don't know an answer to the second part offhand.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the references - I think I'll leave the question open however in hopes for any information on the second part.

Comment: What about $\omega$? It seems that $\mathrm{ZFC}+\{\mathrm{Con}_\alpha(\mathrm{ZFC}):\alpha<\omega\}$ proves its own consistency by the compactness theorem (I mean, if it's inconsistent, then $\mathrm{ZFC}+\{\mathrm{Con}_\alpha(\mathrm{ZFC}):\alpha<n\}$ is inconsistent for some $n$, which contradicts $\mathrm{Con}_n(\mathrm{ZFC})$...). But it can't, because of the second incompleteness theorem... So what am I not seeing?

Comment: @Cronus: this is one of those questions that everyone works out, then forgets, then has to work out again.  Letting $T$ be the theory from the first line of your comment, and letting $T(n) = \text{ZFC} + \{\text{Con}_m(\text{ZFC} : m < n\}$, we are trying to show that $T \vdash \text{Con}(T)$ by contraposition, so we working within $T$ we say: if $\text{Pvbl}_T(0 = 1)$ then, $(\exists r) \text{Pvbl}_{T(r)}(0=1)$ by compactness. However, $T$ does not contain the axiom $(\forall n) \text{Con}_n(\text{ZFC})$, so we do not obtain a contradiction. ...

Comment: From our point of view reasoning about proofs in $T$, the number $r$ may be nonstandard, and so may not correspond to any statement of the form $\text{Con}_n(\text{ZFC})$ that was in $T$.   So what we end up with, as expected, is just that if $T \vdash \text{Pvbl}_T(0=1)$ then $T$ is not sound for statements about provability - indeed, adding the negations of consistency statements to consistent, sound theories is a typical way to generate unsound, consistent theories.

Comment: Just to clarify the key point again, because I am afraid it's hard for me to convey clearly. We work in ZFC and reason about proofs in $T$.  The proof sketch in question wanted to show that there is some $n$ such that $T \vdash \text{Pvbl}(0 = 1) \to \lnot \text{Con}_n(ZFC)$.  What we actually get is that $T \vdash \text{Pvbl}(0 = 1) \to (\exists r) \lnot \text{Con}_r(ZFC)$.  The hole in the sketch happens when it silently moves that existential quantifier from the right side of the turnstile to the left, trying to find a corresponding axiom $\text{Con}_n(\text{ZFC})$ among the axioms for $T$.

Comment: So what you're saying is that if $\phi_n$ is a sentence for every $n$ then $\bigcup \phi_n\cup \{\exists n \neg \phi_n\}$ is not necessarily inconsistent? I don't understand this at all... I would be willing to accept this if we were working in some weak theory, but we're working in $\mathrm{ZFC}$!!! We can construct the natural numbers, so that there are no nonstandard ones...

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation, by the way. Maybe I just don't know enough logic to understand it properly! :]

Comment: @Cronus: I think you have probably seen enough of the incompleteness theorem to recognize the most famous example of that sort. Let $G(n)$ say "$n$ is a Gödel number of a ZFC-proof of $0=1$". Then $\lnot \text{Con}(\text{ZFC})$ is "$(\exists m) G(m)$".  So the theory $\text{ZFC} \cup \{ (\exists m) G(m) \} \cup \{ \lnot G(n) : n \in \omega\}$ is a consistent theory.  This is the kind of thing that motivated Gödel's definition of an $\omega$-consistent theory, as described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory  .

Comment: I see! This is super interesting. Sadly, I never properly studied these things - everything I know if from hearsay... Do you have by any chance a recommendation for a book to get me started? Something that will cover these subtle issues? [It doesn't have to include this exact question about iterated consistency, just enough material for me to be able to address this question - and similar questions - myself].

Comment: In my own opinion, I think that Peter Smith's book  *Introduction to Gödel’s Theorems*  (webpage http://www.logicmatters.net/igt/ ) is the best general introduction. For something shorter, he has a set of lecture notes at http://www.logicmatters.net/igt/godel-without-tears/ which don't go into as many details and side issues, but which are shorter.  @Cronus

Comment: Alright, I'm confused again. So write $T_0=\mathrm{ZFC}$, $T_{n+1}=T_n+\mathrm{Con}(T_n)$, $T=\bigcup_n T_n$. What's wrong with the following proof of $T\implies \mathrm{Con}(T)$? Assume by contradiction $T+\mathrm{Incon}(T)$. By compactness, some finite subset $\Lambda=\{\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m\}$ of $T$ is inconsistent. For each $i=1,..,m$, let $n_i\in\omega$ be such that $\lambda_i\in T_{n_i}$, and let $N=\max n_i$. Then $T_N$ contains $\Lambda$, hence is inconsistent. Which contradicts $\mathrm{Con}(T_{N})\in T_{N+1}\subseteq T$.

Comment: I suppose I'm using compactness wrong, and I guess it has something to do with nonstandard numbers. But we're working in $\mathrm{ZFC}$, so we can construct $\omega$, and we know there are no finite numbers outside of $\omega$... What am I missing? :<

Comment: The idea of the proof is to show, using the notation from the previous comment, that there is an $n$ such that  $T \vdash \lnot\text{Con}(T) \to \lnot T_n$, and then by contraposition $T \vdash T_n \to \text{Con}(T)$ and so $T \vdash \text{Con}(T)$. So we have to keep track of what we are actually assuming: we are not assuming $T + \lnot\text{Con}(T)$, but actually assuming $T \vdash \lnot \text{Con}(T)$.  What we get from compactness (which is provable in $T$) is that $T \vdash \lnot\text{Con}(T) \to (\exists r) \lnot T_r$.  However, we need a standard $n$ to make the proof idea work. @Cronus

Comment: The whole argument comes down to reasoning about provability within $T$. The gap is with trying to instantiate the existential quantifier; it can happen that a theory proves $(\exists r) \phi(r)$ without proving $\phi(n)$ for any standard $n$.

Comment: Alright, I just took a long walk to think about all this and I think I finally understand what you're saying. I'm not sure why you're saying we are assuming $T\vdash \neg\mathrm{Con}(T)$ and not $T+\neg\mathrm{Con}(T)$ (isn't the latter the right thing to do when one attempts to prove by contradiction that $T\vdash \mathrm{Con}(T)$?), but I *think* I get it anyway. I mean, I *did* just show that $T+\neg\mathrm{Con}(T)$  implies $\exists n \neg T_n$! Of course I didn't find a specific $n$.

Comment: The point is, I think, that while $T$ obviously thinks there are no nonstandard numbers, the metatheory (which could be $\mathrm{ZFC}$ or whatever) can't know that it doesn't have nonstandard numbers (exactly because of compactness). So while $T$ contains $T_n$ for every $n$, it doesn't contain $\forall n T_n$. Of course, this is exactly what you said, but sometimes it takes time for these things to sink it...

Comment: Thank you so much for all the answers. This is really cool and mind boggling!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70725/discussion-between-carl-mummert-and-cronus).