# Is it possible to formalize iterative reflection in FOL, and what is its strength?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, large-cardinals

I'll largely present this posting informally, because I'm not certain  if it can be done formally in the language first order logic with identity and membership.

What I want to do is to iterate reflection, the form I'm concerned with is that following:

$$\forall \vec{w} \ \exists \alpha: \varphi(\alpha) \land [\psi \to \psi^{V_\alpha}]$$

Now the idea is change $\varphi$, so we are to have for example formulas $\varphi_0,\varphi_1, \varphi_2,...$, now each formula $\varphi_{i+1}$ is to be defined in terms of $\varphi_i$, more specifically I want $\varphi_{i+1}$ to say that $\alpha$ is a rank of a universe of a theory having axioms: Extensionality, Separation, and reflection...up to $\varphi_i$, the latter is all instances of the following up to $n=i$: $$\forall \vec{w} \ \exists \alpha: \varphi_n(\alpha) \land [\psi \to \psi^{V_\alpha}]$$ for example we begin with $\varphi_0$  to be *"is ordinal"*, now I expect $\varphi_1$ to be *"is inaccessible"*, while $\varphi_2$ to be *"is hyper-inaccessible"*, etc...

> Can this be formalized in first order logic?

> If this can be done, can we extend the indexing of the $\varphi$'s [through using ordinal notations] as to include all recursive ordinals (i.e. ordinals below $\omega_1^ {CK})$? And in this case how can one define the $\varphi_i$'s when $i$ is a limit?

> If the above can be done, what would be the strength of this iterative reflection?

Comment: A small tackle: is there any reason for putting $\varphi$ and $\phi$ in the same formula?

Comment: One issue about your iteration is to including ordinals up to $\omega_1^{CK}$. You have to use ordinal notations instead of recursive ordinals directly (as there would be no other way to express recursive ordinals,) but they are not well-behaved as we naively expected. [The following question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1003154/53976) might be relevant.

Comment: @HanulJeon, althouhg I'm not considering $\varphi$ to be parameterized by $\vec{w}$, but still it has to be there, because we are reflecting formulas $\phi$ to the insde of stages having ranks satisfying $\varphi$. As about ordinal notations, yet I know that, and that's what I meant, to use ordinal notations to represent recursive ordinals and those are the ones that are below the first Church-Kleene $\omega_1$.

Comment: I don't ask their meaning. What I mean is that using $\phi$ and $\varphi$ in the same formula is not a good idea.

Comment: @HanulJeon, why? can you clarify your point?

Comment: $\phi$ and $\varphi$ have different shapes, but some people may confuse they mean the same one since $\varphi$ is a variant of $\phi$.

Comment: @HanulJeon, ah, I see, OK, I've changed the symbols.